# using generic class<T> type as value to matches with enum key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I have this enum with my routes defined like below

```
export enum ApiPath {
    User = "/users",
    Property = "/properties",
     ...
}
```

For example, I call the GenericHttpClient with my interface User in another class.

How can I match my generic type with the enum key like below?

```
    export class GenericHttpClient<T> extends HttpClient {

       async findOne(args: { id: string }): Promise<T> {
       const url = ApiPath[T]; // this is not working 

       return await this.get<T>(`${url}/${args.id}`);
     }

    }
```

'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Is there an easy way to fix this ?

Comment: How do you expect set `T`? Types don't exist at runtime, so `T` doesn't exist at runtime. So, at runtime, where do expect the value of type `T` to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `T` as a value because `T` is a type, and types don't exist at runtime. But you can use a value of type `T` that exists as a property of your instance.

Additionally, enums aren't really designed for you pass around the key of the enum. Instead accept `MyEnum` and pass in a `MyEnum.MyValue`.

---

I'm assuming that you pass in the `ApiPath` value with the constructor of `GenericHttpClient`.

That would mean you need to do this:

```
export class GenericHttpClient<T extends ApiPath> {
    path: T

    constructor(path: T) {
        this.path = path
    }
}

const client = new GenericHttpClient(ApiPath.User)
// client is of type: GenericHttpClient<typeof ApiPath['User']>
```

Now `T` is set by the type of the `path` parameter of the constructor, and then that value is saved to the instance.

Now you can add a `findOne()` method this is very simply this:

```
    async findOne(args: { id: string }): Promise<T> {
        const url = this.path;
        return await this.get<T>(`${url}/${args.id}`);
    }
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.8.4#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-AHwUyeGCNEZjSbTZarZI8-AAIyMAEYAEwAZh5O0Tog1ogAegB+KgW50wV1AA)

Comment: Hey Alex, thank you for your help. That works perfect but now i have the problem that the type of the result from the findeOne() method is ApiPath.key. And that is only the route definition and not the result type i would like. Is there any way that i can have the same logic for my path but that i have a result type from the User interface? Thanks again :) 
Best, Alessandro

Comment: That sounds like a different question. There isn't enough information to answer that at the moment. Post a new question with a link to a [typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpp6zm) that demonstrates whatever incorrect types are happening.